# Haskell: Shuffling deck

Tags: loops, haskell, random, shuffle

I'm working on a lab in which we work with randomness and monads.

The parts of the lab are:

1. write a function randR that generates a random numbers within a given range
2. write a function rollTwoDice that simulates rolling two dice
3. write a function removeCard which randomly removes a card from a list of PlayingCards
4. write a function shuffleDeck which takes the removed card, puts it in front of the deck, then repeats itself until the deck has been completely shuffled.

I have done 1, 2, and 3, but I'm having trouble with 4.

Here's the given code:

RandState.hs

```
module RandState where
import UCState
import System.Random

-- In order to generate pseudo-random numbers, need to pass around generator
--  state in State monad
type RandState a = State StdGen a

-- runRandom runs a RandState monad, given an initial random number generator
runRandom :: RandState a -> StdGen -> a
runRandom (State f) s = res
    where (res, state) = f s

-- rand is a helper function that generates a random instance of any
--  type in the Random class, using the RandState monad.
rand :: Random a => RandState a
rand = do
    gen <- get
    let (x, gen') = random gen
    put gen'
    return x
```

UCState.hs

```
{- 
 - Simplified implementation of the State monad.  The real implementation
 - is in the Control.Monad.State module: using that is recommended for real 
 - programs.
 -}
module UCState where

data State s a = State { runState :: s -> (a, s) }

instance Monad (State s)
    where
        {-
         - return lifts a function x up into the state monad, turning it into
         -  a state function that just passes through the state it receives
         -}
        return x = State ( \s -> (x, s) )

        {- 
         - The >>= combinator combines two functions p and f, and 
         -  gives back a new function (Note: p is originally wrapped in the 
         -  State monad)
         -
         - p: a function that takes the initial state (from right at the start
         - of the monad chain), and gives back a new state and value, 
         - corresponding to the result of the chain up until this >>=
         - f: a function representing the rest of the chain of >>='s
         -}
        (State p) >>= f = State ( \initState -> 
                                  let (res, newState) = p initState
                                      (State g) = f res
                                  in g newState )

-- Get the state
get :: State s s  
get = State ( \s -> (s, s) )

-- Update the state
put :: s -> State s ()
put s = State ( \_ -> ((), s))
```

Here's my code, which I just wrote inside RandState.hs since I couldn't figure out how to import it (help with importing would be nice as well, although not what I'm most concerned about at this point):

```
randR :: Random a => (a, a) -> RandState a
randR (lo, hi) = do
    gen <- get
    let (x, gen') = randomR (lo, hi) gen
    put gen'
    return x

testRandR1 :: IO Bool
testRandR1 = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    let genR = runRandom (randR (1,5)) gen :: Int
    return (genR <=5 && genR >=1)

testRandR2 :: IO Bool
testRandR2 = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    let genR = runRandom (randR (10.0, 11.5)) gen :: Double
    return (genR <= 11.5 && genR >= 10.0)

rollTwoDice :: RandState Int
rollTwoDice = do
    gen <- get
    let (a, gen') = randomR (1, 6) gen :: (Int, StdGen)
    put gen'
    let (b, gen'') = randomR (1, 6) gen' :: (Int, StdGen)
    put gen''
    return $ a + b

testRollTwoDice :: IO Bool
testRollTwoDice = do
    gen <- newStdGen
    let genR = runRandom (rollTwoDice) gen
    return (genR <= 12 && genR >= 2)

-- Data types to represent playing cards
data CardValue = King | Queen | Jack | NumberCard Int
    deriving (Show, Eq)
data CardSuit = Hearts | Diamonds | Spades | Clubs
    deriving (Show, Eq)
data PlayingCard = PlayingCard CardSuit CardValue
    deriving (Show, Eq)

{-
 - fullCardDeck will be a deck of cards, 52 in total, with a King, a Queen, 
 - a Jack and NumberCards from 1 to 10 for each suit.
 -}
-- fullCardDeck and its definition were given in the lab
fullCardDeck :: [PlayingCard]
fullCardDeck = [ PlayingCard s v | s <- allsuits, v <- allvals ] where
        allvals = King : Queen : Jack : [ NumberCard i | i <- [1..10] ]
        allsuits = [Hearts, Diamonds, Spades, Clubs]

removeCard :: [a] -> RandState [a]
removeCard deck = do
    gen <- get
    let n = runRandom (randR(1, length (deck))) gen :: Int
    let (xs, ys) = splitAt (n-1) deck
    return $ head ys : xs ++ tail ys

shuffleDeck deck = do
    gen <- get
    let f deck = head $ runRandom (removeCard deck) gen
    return $ take (length(deck)) (iterate f deck)
```

shuffleDeck doesn't work. The error:

```
RandState.hs:88:31:
    Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a0 = [a0]
    Expected type: [a0] -> [a0]
      Actual type: [a0] -> a0
    In the first argument of `iterate', namely `f'
    In the second argument of `take', namely `(iterate f deck)'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely `take 52 (iterate f deck)'
```

I guess the issue is that iterate takes a value, applies a function to this value, applies the function to the result, and so on, returning an infinite list of results. I'm handing iterate a function that takes a list, and returns a card, so the result cannot be passed to the next iteration. What would be a better way to approach this problem (4)? I'm also worried that my removeCard function is a little janky since it just puts the "removed" card in front, which I did to make shuffleDeck easier to write. If necessary, what would be a better way to approach this problem (3)?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: my best guest is take out 'head $' from  f, as you want to iterate over the whole deck (and not over the first card!). It should at least typecheck.

edit: yeah that's the way, you'll have to fix the take argument, but you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: `import` should import things :)

Comment: Thanks MdxBhmt, I removed head $ from f, then mapped head to the iterated list. I can't get shuffleDeck to display its results though, apparently because there is no instance of (Show (RandState [PlayingCard])). Any ideas for that? And jozefg, I already tried doing import last night and it didn't work, but I just tried it again now and it worked. Maybe your comment was the x factor, so thanks.

Comment: @user2967411 You can't print a RandState since it's a function, you'll have to `runRandom` and print the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stop trying to `runRandom` inside your functions. You should only use `runRandom` once you actually want a result (for example - to print the result, since you can't do this inside the monad). Trying to 'escape' from the monad is a futile task and you will only produce confusing and often non-functioning code. The final output of all of your functions will be inside the monad, so you don't need to escape anyways.

Note that

```
gen <- get
let n = runRandom (randR(1, length (deck))) gen :: Int
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
n <- randR (1, length deck)
```

The `<-` syntax executes a computation in monad on the right and 'puts' it into the variable name on the left.

**Shuffling:**

```
shuffleR [] = return []   
shuffleR xs = do      
  (y:ys) <- removeR xs  -- 1
  zs <- shuffleR ys     -- 2
  return (y:zs)         -- 3
```

The function is straightforward recursion: 
1) extract a random element, 2) shuffle what is left, 3) combine the results.

edit: extra info requested:

```
randSum :: (Num b, Random b) => State StdGen b
randSum = do
  a <- randR (1,6) 
  b <- randR (1,6) 
  return $ a + b
```

compiles just fine. Judging from your description of the error, you are trying to call this function inside the `IO` monad. You cannot mix monads (or at least not so simply). If you want to 'execute' something of type `RandState` inside of `IO` you will indeed have to use `runRandom` here.

`n <- randR (1, length deck)` makes `n` an `Int` because `length deck` has type `Int` and `randR :: Random a => (a, a) -> RandState a`, so from the context we can infer `a ~ Int` and the type unifies to `(Int, Int) -> RandState Int`.

Just to recap

Wrong:

```
try = do
  a <- randomIO      :: IO Int
  b <- randR (0,10)  :: RandState Int
  return $ a + b     -- monads don't match!
```

Right:

```
try = do
  a <- randomIO                                 :: IO Int
  let b = runRandom (randR (0,10)) (mkStdGen a) :: Int    -- 'execute' the randstate monad
  return $ a + b
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That made a lot of sense. Now I have a question on rollTwoDice though. I went back and saw that the problem requires me to use randR in my implementation. So I hoped that I could just write `a <- randR (1,6) // b <- randR (1,6) // return $ a + b` but this won't compile. I'm a bit confused about how n <- randR (1, length deck) successfully made n an integer (at least that's how I understood it), but adding a <- randR (1,6) with b <- randR (1,6) doesn't just give me the sum of a and b. The function expects type `IO t0` but I am apparently giving it type `RandState Integer`.

Comment: Updated answer with reply.